# Use YoutubeAPI to play youtube video until a particular time and pause

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a way to use the Youtube API to play a video until a certain point in the video and then pause it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've modified the code from the [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to pause play after a certain number of seconds.

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/hnkK7/737/)</kbd>

The code works by waiting for the `onPlayerStateChange` event. When the event fires, it checks the event to see if it's a `PLAYING` event. If it is, it calculates the remaining time from the current time (`getCurrentTime()` method) to the desired pause point (hardcoded as the `stopPlayAt` variable). It sets a Javascript timer to wait that difference and then pass the API a command to pause the video.

Comment: This was so awesome. Thanks so much.

Comment: This only works, if the user is not messing with the buttons, so please consider it when coding ;)

Comment: @Nippey, not sure I know what you mean… The code I wrote automatically clears the timeout on every user interaction. Then, if the action is play, it recalculates the timeout necessary to the next stop. This should be enough to work around any user interaction and get the timer to always stop at the correct time.

Comment: If the user doesn't do anything but bandwidth limitations cause the video to spend any time buffering while your js counter is going then you'll be off and pause/end early.  Something to consider.

Comment: It should work even around buffering (untested, ymmv :-p). The YouTube API has a separate state for buffering (`YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING`, see docs for [onStateChange](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkK7/)). The way I coded it the stop timer is cleared when the player state changes to anything but playing. When the state changes back to `YT.PlayerState.PLAYING`, the timer is restarted with a new timeout calculated from the current playing position.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `cueVideoById` in Object syntax to achieve this.

See here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#cueVideoById

This is the way it should look like to start a video like this.

```
//Minimal Example
player.cueVideoById({videoId:String, endSeconds:Number});
player.playVideo();
```

---

EDIT: The above sample stops the video. If you want to pause it, a little more action is required by the JavaScript code.

In detail, you have to poll for the right time.

```
function checkTime() {
   if ( player.getCurrentTime() == finishTime )
      player.pauseVideo()
   else
      setInterval(checkTime, 500);
}

checkTime();
```

Or keep track of the time in JS:

```
var duration = finishTime - player.getCurrentTime();
player.playVideo()
setInterval("player.pauseVideo();", duration*1000);
```

Comment: Cool, this is a step in the right direction. However, I want it to pause at that point, rather than ending the video. Any way I can do that? (I say pause because I don't want the other video suggestions to show up)