# Play between certain time onclick button - youtube iframe api

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I have one Youtube video which has 6 episodes and I have six buttons which onclick will skip to the start of that particular episode.

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52jnfsk7/7/) for that.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'L6cVcbkx8l8',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();

        $('#episode1').click(function(evt){
            console.log($(evt.currentTarget).val());
            player.seekTo(50)
        })
        $('#episode2').click(function(evt){
            console.log($(evt.currentTarget).val());
            player.seekTo(100)
        })
        $('#episode3').click(function(evt){
            console.log($(evt.currentTarget).val());
            player.seekTo(150)
        })
      }
```

What I am actually trying to do is when someone is clicking on episode2, it should play between only that time code (say xx.yy to aa.bb). So, how do I mention the end time for each episode onclick.

Comment: So do you mean, it should get paused at the end of a selected episode.

Comment: Yes. exactly. It should pause. because I don't want suggestions videos to appear by stopping it.

Comment: You dont have to stop it. You can pause it at the end of each episode, if it is last episode you can stop it at 00:00

Comment: Yes. But how do I mention the time to pause? I know player.pauseVideo(300); would not work.

Comment: How about right after `player.seekTo(100);` just `setTimeout(pause,50000);` and don't forget to create `function pause(){player.pauseVideo();}` - I assume your parameters are seconds, and setTimeout uses milliseconds.

Comment: I tried that. But it pauses the video after x time from the click of the button. So sometimes it pauses the video before even the video buffers.

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152415/use-youtubeapi-to-play-youtube-video-until-a-particular-time-and-pause) should solve your problem. In short, it calculates the difference between current and remaining time and pauses a video at x seconds before the end.