# I can't put a loop and limit the video size to 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Good evening! I got this code here on the forum and it's working fine, but I'm not able to put a loop for the video to keep repeating all the time and the time of 2 minutes. When he arrives in 2 minutes he will return to the beginning. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    </head>
  <body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'osz5tVY97dQ',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'playsinline': 1 },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.mute();
    event.target.playVideo();
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

***Option 1:*** Thanks to this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152787/12511801), I've modified the code for play a video on a loop.

This code will playback after 4 seconds.

```js
(function() {
  var stopPlayAt = 4, // Stop play at time in seconds - in this case, 4 seconds.
    stopPlayTimer; // Reference to settimeout call

  // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  // after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
      "height": "315",
      "width": "560",
      "videoId": "xe-f4gokRBs",
      "events": {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  // This automatically starts the video playback when the player is loaded.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    var time, rate, remainingTime;
    clearTimeout(stopPlayTimer);
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      time = player.getCurrentTime();
      // Add .4 of a second to the time in case it's close to the current time
      // (The API kept returning ~9.7 when hitting play after stopping at 10s)
      if (time + .4 < stopPlayAt) {
        rate = player.getPlaybackRate();
        remainingTime = (stopPlayAt - time) / rate;
        stopPlayTimer = setTimeout(pauseVideo, remainingTime * 1000);
      }
    }
  }

  function pauseVideo() {
    player.stopVideo(); // Stops the video.
    player.playVideo(); // Plays the video from the beginning.
  }
})();
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

---

***Option 2:*** Here is a shorter version I found [here](https://codepen.io/MendleMeyer/pen/NEQoRw?editors=1010):

```
<div id="player"></div>

// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
// ↓↓ Set these values as you need:
var startSeconds = 35;
var endSeconds = 55;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: "u9Mv98Gr5pY",
    fitToBackground: true,
    pauseOnScroll: false,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1, // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 0, // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0, // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1, // Hide the Youtube Logo
      fs: 0, // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3, // Hide the Video Annotations
      start: startSeconds, // Set loop start time
      end: endSeconds, // Set loop end time
      autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
      disablekb: 1,
      rel: 0, // Hide video recommendations
      playsinline: 1,
      mute: 1
    },
    events: {
      onStateChange: function(e) {
        if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          player.seekTo(startSeconds);
          player.playVideo();
          player.mute();
        }
      },
      onReady: function(e) {
        player.mute();
        player.seekTo(startSeconds);
        player.playVideo();
      }
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```