# youtube-iframe-api - Youtube Premium to loop a youtube video?

Tags: api, loops, video, iframe, youtube

i'm trying to loop a video (this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rh0zPwIBwYU) when it finished but even if i'm using this tool : https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=fr by modifying parameters, it doesn't work...

Do we need to be youtube premium to loop a youtube video ? Because other videos are offered to me when my video has finished playing

[image]

Kind regards.
Geoffrey

I tried to modify several parameters but it doesn't work...

Comment: Check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71858565/12511801) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74881744/12511801)